# Spring Boot WebMvcConfigurerAdapter Serving Broken Images

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-boot, filesystems

[image]

Following code below is Spring Boot Serving Images Configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        /*registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:/home/test/images");*/
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:///C:/test/images/");

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Till Yesterday, It was serving properly.But all of sudden its serving like this.
If I try to access same image using file path url its working fine eg

> file:///C:/test/images/profile/5880b70d91286e0318863818/APM1243//originalImage_k3kf6nxil1en8yi_.jpeg

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Its not because of backend code(Java), image was not displaying properly. Its because of browser, when I do empty cache reload image is rendering properly.